# Redirect outgoing connection to localhost

Tags: linux, redirect, iptables

Is it possible to redirect outgoing connection back to localhost using iptables?

For example, if php script requests  someonlinesite.com/bla.php then it would redirect to 127.0.0.1/bla.php

OS: Debian 7

Answer (score 1):

The question does not really make much sense the way it currently is asked.

Most likely you are trying to redirect a http request? Then you should take a closer look at your systems name resolution, since that is the step that translates the host name `someonlinesite.com` to an ip address. So that is where you want to manipulate.

You might also want to consider using a proxy as an alternative. But a pure `iptables` based solution is questionable, since in typical setups the local http server will not react to incoming requests to a remote ip address...

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 0/0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replies, i managed to do it with hosts file.
/etc/hosts

127.0.0.1  domain.com

Now it redirects always to localhost when script tryes to reach domain.com